# Move one particular view up when opening a keyboard not the entire layout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, layout

I want functionality like Facebook like when we create any post with an image on it only they push one bar on top of the image, not the entire layout. In my case, I am using NestedScrollView as a parent with child ConstraintLayout and the bar is designed in Linear layout.

This is my app:

[image]

I want something like this:

[image]

This is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:fillViewport="true">


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.03" />


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.97" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/select_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_15dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:foreground="@drawable/ripple"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/dimen_5dp"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dimen_5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dimen_5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/left_arrow"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.00"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.00" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView

        android:id="@+id/back_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_15dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_bold"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/dimen_5dp"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dimen_5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dimen_5dp"
        android:text="@string/new_post"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/select_back"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.00" />


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/postTextview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_15dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
        android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/dimen_5dp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/dimen_5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dimen_5dp"
        android:text="@string/post"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/back_title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.00" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="@color/grey_text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/select_back"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />


    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rock"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/white"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/line" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_bold"
        android:text="Dwayne johnson"
        android:textColor="@color/textview_black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/profile_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/line" />


    <com.skyfishjy.library.RippleBackground
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="44dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/line"
        app:rb_color="#29B6F6"
        app:rb_duration="2000"
        app:rb_radius="5dp"
        app:rb_rippleAmount="3"
        app:rb_scale="4">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/world"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="TODO"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/world" />

    </com.skyfishjy.library.RippleBackground>


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/down_arrow"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_down_sign_to_navigate"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/line" />


    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="8dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rel"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="#DCDCDC"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_image" />


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/category1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/personal"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
        app:textAllCaps="false" />


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/category2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/post_btn_bg"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/awareness"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/category1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
        app:textAllCaps="false" />


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/category3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/post_btn_bg"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/scheme"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/category2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
        app:textAllCaps="false" />


    <View
        android:id="@+id/line1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/grey_text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/category3" />


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/write_post"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/line1"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/post_edit_text_bg"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:hint="What's on your mind..."
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textColor="@color/textview_black"
        android:textColorHint="@color/grey2_text"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/line1" />


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/timelineImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/write_post">


    </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView>

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/timelineVideo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/write_post"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.072">

    </VideoView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/item_bg"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/camera"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_camera" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/gallery"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/gallery" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Tried everything in the manifest

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" 
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

but nothing worked. All are pushing my entire layout up.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because, you are using NestedScrollView as parent check by replacing NestedScrollView with any other layout

Comment: Nope, nothing happens still the issue.  I made ConstraintLayout as a parent and removed NestedScrollview. Still, my entire layout is moving up.

Answer (score 0):

add This in your meniFest file beside your activity tag

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

and,put scrollView as a parent layout in your xml file

Comment: Tried with Scrollview with android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" but nothing happen.